# How to maintain the indexing in html when posting data to server in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I have a form made in html which is used to crate heading and text. suppose I click on button for add heading and then on another button for adding text.

Now I have a heading (input type="text") and I have a text (which is textarea). using [jQuery sortable plugin](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) I make them up down in the html page.

Now my problem is user can up down the heading and text. I want to generate html on the back and create the html.

Now in the code how I can find which one come first, head or text. I first try with looping the Request.Form and generate the html.

If I use Request.Form approach there will be one key for every key, for example.

```
<input type="text" name="head"/>
```

Request.form join them with comma, What about if someone enter it with comma. How I can separate them. If someone have workaround for this, please help.

2. 2nd idea is using input like head[], this way I can use them in parameter like List head, (in ActionResult). My problem still remain same, How I can figure out which come first  "head" or "text".

Is there anyway to figure out on server which input tag come first.

Thanks

Comment: I would add another data array where you save the order from jquery sortable. Probably jQuery sortable already provides the order somewhere.

Comment: btw, google finds quite some stackoverflow answers on that topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+sortable+order

Comment: @Danmoreng here is the plugin https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/,  I update the question as well, I am thinking to put the number as suffix in form before form-submit. this way I can find out on server. any other way to it more easily.

Comment: @Danmoreng I try with "Request.Form.ToString()" and it's give me all values separated by & with order maintained. it''s looking good solution.What issue can happen with this implementation.

Comment: Do you need both 1. Main list and 2. Each item including head and text to be sortable? and you need to know the order of both lists serverside?

Comment: @AliSeyedi the plugin does sorting and working well, I need to figure out on server which one come first which I do use Request.Form.ToString() as my previous comment.